# How to test JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, testing

Although been coding JS for a while I never really focused on formal testing any more then usual clicking around in hope that something will break. Now I would like to see how this should be done properly and wonder how testing is performed while coding JavaScript web app. As I understand, in a nutshell, test are written for every method and return values asserted.

Now, how this fits into JavaScript development where JS interacts with DOM, JS animates things around, calculates distances based on browser window and so on and on. How would I test for possible problems other then click around till something breaks? In addition multiple browser and all this got me really confused.

My web app uses module pattern, is coded in strict mode, uses jQuery and bunch of plugins. Clicking till breaks approach works fine so far but I'm sure there is better way and if someone could give me an idea how this should be done that would be much appreciated.

Comment: You may benefit from the Aptana Eclipse plugin- https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enUS439US439&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enUS439US439&sclient=psy-ab&q=Aptana+Eclipse+plugin+&oq=Aptana+Eclipse+plugin+&gs_l=hp.3..0l4.4995.4995.2.5235.1.1.0.0.0.0.97.97.1.1.0...0.0.0..1c.1.17.psy-ab.3zf51GdVJM4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48293060,d.dmQ&fp=7c755eaf540a7915&ion=1&biw=1344&bih=737

Comment: Lucky for you, Rebecca Murphey recently wrote [Writing Testable JavaScript](http://alistapart.com/article/writing-testable-javascript)

Comment: @Nile, this is great article you linked and it exactly answers my question yet although I tried googling it I couldnt find it! If you could make this comment into an answer I would be happy to accept it. Please do that before Stackoverflow police closes this question as it seems if there is no line of code in the question itself it will be marked as not appropriate, no matter it helps people or not

Comment: @spirytus Your question was closed because it would easily spark debate and was wayyyyy to general. You could've easily searched this online. I'm glad the article helped, though.

Comment: @Nile totally understand and I assure you sparking debate wasn't my intention. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 3):

In general, the kind of testing you describe with UI interactions is done using a tool which emulates browser behavior.

For example, Selenium can be used to automate different browsers and click on things, and then assert the page's state is as expected.

Another useful tool is phantomjs, which essentially is a headless scriptable browser.

These can be used to do integration/feature testing of the full page. Using these, you would write a test script which defines some interactions ("click X, hover over Y"), and then verify the page's state is what you want (for example, by checking if a CSS selector matches or if a div is visible etc.)

There is also a wide variety of unit testing tools for JavaScript which can be used to test individual JS modules that don't use DOM or such.

Comment: OYA! Selenium is fabulous, yes. that's a firefox-only tool though, yes?